# A program to find number of occurrences of a sub-string in a string without using library function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

So far I have reached here, but program always returns 1. 
I don't want to use library function. Please help!
Since, I'm a beginner I want the code to be as simple as possible. Thanks!

```
str = input("Enter The String: ")
substr = input("Enter The Sub-String: ")
l = len(str)
count = 0
es = ''
for i in range (l):
    es += str[i]
    if es == substr:
       if str[i+1] != ' ':
          count = 0
        else:
            count += 1
            es = ''
print (count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't call your own variable `str`; it masks a Python built-in.

Secondly, you are iterating over the wrong value, the length of the substring not the string.

Thirdly, your logic is completely wrong, you build the input string up to the length of the substring, testing each time if it is the substring, and reset count if you reach a space.

Instead, try:

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i:i+len(substring)] == substring:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

This moves a "window" of the same length as the substring along the string, counting 1 for each match.

Better yet, as JAB suggsts, just use `count`!

Comment: It adds 1 more to the occurrence. If the occurrence is 2 it will show 3.

Comment: There's an issue with your method. What happens when the string is `aaaaaaa` and the substring is `aaa`? If you want to avoid overlaps you'll need to move the index variable out of the loop declaration, probably switch to `while i < len(string):` for the declaration, and do `i += len(substring)` whenever a match is found.

Comment: @VedantGanjoo yes, sorry, fixed that typo.

Comment: Please, can you give me the code. I'm too confused. Probably looking at the code will clear my confusion.

Comment: @JAB do you want to avoid overlaps? That is the way `count` works, but it's not necessarily right.

Comment: @VedantGanjoo I have given you the code. Look, it's there, in my answer ^^

Comment: Yes, but without the library functions.

Comment: @VedantGanjoo do you mean `len` and `range`? You could use `while` loops to get the length of each string, but that seems a bit like self-harming. Are you allowed `print`? Slicing `[:]`? `if`?

Comment: Yes I can use while print and slice and if.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Let us say if our subs-tring is 'bob' and the string contains 'bobs', the program still adds +1 to the count.

Comment: @VedantGanjoo yes, that's correct, `"bob"` is a sub-string of `"bobs"`. If you have to match with spaces, the programme gets more complex - what about punctuation, etc?

Comment: the program should just look for 'bob' and if it has any punctuations or any other word like 's' or anything else, it should not consider it. Let the code be complex that doesn't matter.

Comment: @VedantGanjoo I guess complexity doesn't matter to you, but I'm writing it! This comment discussion has gone on too long; I will leave you to make appropriate modifications to the code to meet your specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as simple as possible, you should use the built-in functionality Python provides. And I would not recommend using `str` as a variable name as that's one of the built-in types; it works because `str` is not a reserved keyword, but hiding the `str` class may not be a good idea.

```
s = input("Enter The String: ")
sub_s = input("Enter The Sub-String: ")

print(s.count(sub_s))
```

From the docstring for `str.count`:

> S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
>
> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Comment: But, that's what I don't want to use. If it's complex no worries. But, no library function.

Comment: @VedantGanjoo You stated in your question that you want it as simple as possible. There is no shame in using the functionality Python provides you without any import of modules; as a beginner, you should be learning how to use the features that come with the language before you start trying to reimplement them.

Comment: That's basically like someone wants to learn driving and you tell them to get a taxi.

Comment: @VedantGanjoo Then you shouldn't be using Python, where all operators are defined in terms of what are effectively library functions. `a += str[i]` is actually `a = a.__add__(str.__getitem__(i))`, and so on (possibly with some exceptions on built-ins for efficiency, but that's the general case).

Comment: @thg435 I'd say it's more like someone who wants to get out there and drive without spending time to learn the basics of safe driving first.

Comment: (Continuing with a new comment because I waited too long editing the first one:) Having someone use Python and then telling them "don't use any library methods" is about as silly as having someone use Java and telling them "don't use any object-oriented concepts". I could understand an exercise of this sort for, say, C, but with Python you're better off using the builtins first and then branching off. I suppose that's just my personal opinion on how programming should be taught, though; introduce a concept/aspect of a language first, then go through how it works, rather than doing the reverse.